# Overriding std functions

Tags: c++, overriding, std

I'd like to override the behavior of an std function, say std::time.  Is it possible to call std::time and have it routed through my custom function?

Comment: To clarify:

I want to hijack the use of ::time in another precompiled library.
Portability is not important.  Let's assume the compiler and platform are very specific and will never change.

Comment: In that case, no, it can't be done. Not in C++. It could probably technically be done *outside* C++. Modify the runtime library, hook into that. But once the library has been compiled, the functions it calls are fixed. It doesn't do name lookup and overload resolution at runtime. it simply calls the function that was determined at compile-time. And if the compiler determined that the *standard* std::time function should be called, then it has generated code for calling that.

Comment: @jalf you really should put your comment into an answer.

Comment: True, and Tim's comment should have been edited into the question. :)

Answer (score 12):

The `std` namespace is off limits, generally speaking. Adding new functions, overloads, classes or anything else to the `std` namespace is **undefined behavior*.

The *only* exception is *template specializations*. You may provide specializations of functions in the `std` namespace. A function where this is often done is `std::swap`.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a very bad idea.  Kind of like redefining `true` or `false`.  A better way would be to write your own wrapper function, say `tim_time()`, which may or may not call `std::time()` internally.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling it `std::time`, route all calls that you might sometimes override through a different namespace.

```
namespace mystd{
    using namespace std;
    void time() { ... }
}

// ...
mystd::time();  // not std::time
mystd::copy(...); // calls std::copy, unless you override it like time()
```

Then the call to `mystd::time` will call the modified version of the function.  If you call non-overridden function, for example, `mystd::copy`, it will be correctly resolved to the original std function.

Answer (score 1):

Not portably. On the understanding that the standard doesn't define what happens, you can usually define whatever symbols and functions you like in namespace std, or link against a library that defines those symbols, or whatever. It's just undefined behaviour. So all you can do is suck it and see, and hope it doesn't break in the next release of your compiler.

That said, with most compilers it will probably mostly work, provided that you avoid a one-definition-rule clash with the "real" std::time. This is because most compilers don't actually do anything special with namespace std, and the header files and libraries they use to implement it are not really any different from header files and libraries you could write yourself.

Dima is absolutely right, though, that going off-standard like this is a almost always a very bad idea. Maybe if you're stuck in some debugging hell where you basically want to add logging to std::time, but can't, then it's worth thinking about. Otherwise don't go there. If you want to test some code, to see whether it works correctly at various times, then pass that code a parameter (or template parameter) specifying which time function it should call.

Answer (score 1):

On some platforms, you can pull this off.  In your source code, define the function, i.e.

```
extern "C" time_t time(time_t *value)
{
        ...
}
```

If you're lucky, the linker will bind your version of `std::time` more tightly than the one from the standard library.  Of course, there's no guarantee that this will work, or be linked the way you want.  And as a downside, you no longer have any access to the original `std::time`.

As everyone else has posted, this isn't portable behavior.  I'm pretty sure it works on Linux.  I'm also fairly certain it doesn't work on Windows (linker complains about the conflict).