# Is it safe to overload std::floor in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, std

**Important:** question is about C++17, before `std::floor` became a template.

Lets say there is a user-defined template:

```cpp
template<class Unit>
class Pixels {};
```

Is it safe to overload `std::floor` for such template?
Like this:

```cpp
namespace std {
  template<class Unit>
  auto floor(const Pixels<Unit>&) -> Pixels<Unit>;
}
```

AFAIK it is prohibited to extend `std`.
But this way other code can work with `Pixels` in the same way it works with standard `float`/`double`.

Like this:

```cpp
template<Unit>
class Point {
public:
  Unit x;
  Unit y;
  auto floor() -> Point<Unit> {
    return { std::floor(x), std::floor(y) }; 
  }
};

Point<float>().floor();
Point<Pixels<float>>().floor();
```

Are there any exceptions for such use-cases that allow extension of `std`?

Note: suggested [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375018/overriding-std-functions) is unrelated, because instead of altering the behavior of existing function I want to add new overload.

Comment: as `std::floor` is a template you can provide a specialisation but not an overload

Comment: @AlanBirtles what about C++17?

Comment: You can add things to `std` namespace only when documentation says you can (for example std::hash specializations). In all other cases it is Undefined Behavior. Since `std::floor` doesn't say anything about this you shouldn't do it.

Comment: What is actual problem? Why you need this? I'm pretty sure there are alternative ways to fix your actual problem. For example use of Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL) may be a nice approach.

Comment: @MarekR I want to provide 3rd party functions with a way to `floor`/`ceil` my class the same way as `float`/`double`. For instance, to replace something like `Point<float>`/`Rect<float>` with `Point<Pixels<float>>`/`Rect<Pixels<float>>`.

Comment: Looks like [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: @AlanBirtles No, that applies only to class templates. Adding an overload or a specialization causes UB. `std::floor` may or may not be implemented as a template or multiple overloads or a mixture of that.

Comment: @hopeless-programmer `std::floor` is not customizable. You can't do that. However, you can make `floor(my_type)` (without `std::`) work by adding an overload of `floor` in the same namespace where you declare your class, so that it will be found via ADL. I am not sure whether you really want to do that, because it relies on the user using the `using std::floor; floor(/*...*/);` idiom which typically isn't used for `floor` because it isn't expected to be a customization point.

Comment: @hopeless-programmer *question is about C++17, before std::floor became a template...."* No, Looks [like](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor) it already was a template from C++11.

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, why not `my_floor`?

Comment: @PaulSanders maybe he has a generic template that accepts `T point` as an argument which might be just a `float`, which does work with `std::floor`. But in that case `using std::floor` idiom looks fine. Or the suggested `my_floor` that could conditionally invoke `std::floor`